# Unity C# Constructor is not called properly

Tags: c#, list, class, unity-game-engine, initialization

I have some trouble initializing strings from their constructor when a new List element is created from the Unity inspector while in edit mode.

All it does is writing "Call test" to console, but not initializing its name and description to the placeholder texts.

```
public class StatsManager : MonoBehaviour {   
    [System.Serializable]
    public class StatValue {
        public string name;
        public string description;
        public int currentValue;

        public StatValue(){
            this.name = "Times hit";
            this.description = "This is how much you have been hit since the start of the game.";
            Debug.Log("Call test");
        }
    }

    [SerializeField]
    public List<StatsManager.StatValue> stats;
}
```

Comment: I can't see any call to that constructor...

Comment: The constructor gets called as I get a debug.log message in the console. It will be automaticly called on instanciation.

Comment: Not sure I understand. So there is some hidden code where stats = new List<StatsManager.StatValue>() and stats.Add(new StatsManager.StatValue()), right?

Comment: @McMidas: you showed us some code. You did not show us the place where you used said code, so how are we supposed to help you debug what is happening?

Comment: oh I forgot to mention that I edit the list in the inspector of unity

Comment: So unity creates the list and creates the stats? Whatever, no clue...

Comment: Guys... This is unity3d it calls the code as long as it is correctly mapped to untiy3d editor. What you need is to use `GameObject` and `GetComponent` to set those values

Comment: @12seconds No I configure the list while I am in edit mode so I want to init this texts as placeholders when I increase the size of the list. therefor I know what to write something similar for the current stat.

Comment: Did you make any changes on the editor on unity3d? Standard behavior on unity3d If you've modified the value of a variable in the inspector, then the modified value always overrides the value supplied in the code, even if you change it. Also, I don't think constructor will work if you are creating this `placeholder`,try setting it on the member like `public string name = "Times hit"`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a solution in case somebody has the same problem. No need of cTor or ISerializableCallbackReceiver. This uses the Reset Callback (from the coq) that will also call at instanciation. Cheers!

```
 [System.Serializeable]
 public class Test {
     int value = 500;
 }
 public class TestManager : MonoBehaviour {
     public Test testInt;
     public List<Test> testInts;
     void Reset(){
         testInts = new List<Test>(){
             new Test()
         };
     }
 }
```

from https://answers.unity.com/questions/1467289/default-value-on-list-vanished.html?childToView=1467368#comment-1467368